# Qt X.509 client authentication using smartcard

Tags: c++, qt, smartcard, client-certificates, qnetworkaccessmanager

I am trying to access a protected site in `c++` using [`QNetworkAccessManager`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) and basic rest requests.
The site requires a `x.509 client certificate`.
I have a `smartcard` which I would like to use to `authenticate` to this site.

What I read is, that I need a private key to authenticate, which I can then set for the request in the `sslConfiguration()` using `.setPrivateKey()`, but the smartcard does not allow me to use the private key on the smartcard.

Does anyone know, how Google Chrome, Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge are doing the requests to access those sites? Firefox seems not to work with the smartcard-reader.

I know, they are using the [`CNG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376210(v=vs.85).aspx) of windows, but what do I have to do or keep in mind, so, that I can use the smartcard to authenticate to this site and use the REST Endpoint.

The following is what I already tried to get the private key from the smartcard and attach it to the request:

```
void MainWindow::getPrivateCert()
{
    NCRYPT_PROV_HANDLE hProv;
    if (NCryptOpenStorageProvider(&hProv, MS_SMART_CARD_KEY_STORAGE_PROVIDER, 0) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            std::cout << "error 1" << std::endl;
            return;
    }

    NCryptKeyName *keyName = new NCryptKeyName();
    VOID *enumState = NULL;
    int certCounter = 0;
    while (NCryptEnumKeys(hProv, NULL, &keyName, &enumState, 0) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        //std::wcout << keyName->pszName << std::endl;
        NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE keyHandle;
        if (NCryptOpenKey(hProv, &keyHandle, keyName->pszName, keyName->dwLegacyKeySpec, 0) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            BYTE *name = new BYTE[1024];
            DWORD nameLen;
            if (NCryptGetProperty(keyHandle, NCRYPT_NAME_PROPERTY, name, 1024, &nameLen, 0) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
                for (int i = 0; i < nameLen; i++) {
                    if (name[i] == 0) { continue; }
                    std::wcout << (wchar_t)name[i];
                }
                std::cout << std::endl;
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
            BYTE *size = new BYTE[1024];
            DWORD sizeLen;
            int certSize = 0;
            if (NCryptGetProperty(keyHandle, NCRYPT_LENGTH_PROPERTY, size, 1024, &sizeLen, 0) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
                std::cout << "size: ";
                for (int i = sizeLen; i >= 0; i--) {
                        std::wcout << (int)size[i];
                        int factor = pow(10, i);
                        certSize += (int)size[i] * factor;
                }
                std::cout << std::endl;
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
            printf("%d\n", certSize);
            BYTE *cert = new BYTE[certSize*2];
            DWORD certLen;
            if (NCryptGetProperty(keyHandle, NCRYPT_CERTIFICATE_PROPERTY, cert, certSize*2, &certLen, 0) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
                printf("%d\n", certLen);
                this->m_cert = new char[certLen];
                this->m_certSize = certLen;
                for (int i = 0; i < certLen; i++) {
                    //std::wcout << (char)cert[i];
                    this->m_cert[i] = cert[i];
                }
                std::cout << std::endl;
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
            NCryptFreeObject(keyHandle);
        }
        if(certCounter == this->certNumber) {
            break;
        }
        certCounter++;
    }
    NCryptFreeBuffer(keyName);
}

getPrivateCert();
std::cout.write(this->m_cert, this->m_certSize) << std::endl;
QSslKey key(QByteArray(cert, certSize), QSsl::KeyAlgorithm::Rsa, QSsl::EncodingFormat::Der, QSsl::KeyType::PrivateKey, "");
QNetworkRequest request(QUrl(this->m_restEndpoint));
request.sslConfiguration().setPrivateKey(key);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::KnownHeaders::UserAgentHeader, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36");
manager->get(request);
```

I am pretty sure, that I am missing some very important steps, but I can't really find any useful information for c++ x.509 client authentication using a smartcard.